# Best way to compare 2D pdf and 2D histogram

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, data-analysis, image-processing

I previously asked a related [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3786025/mean-squared-error-but-large-bin-sizes-can-give-small-error) but got no reply.

So more generally: I am generating points from a 2D multivariate distribution, I then generate a 2D histogram of these points using different methods and settings. I want to find the best histogram (i.e. the one that matches the true 2D multivariate distribution the best).

What is the best way to do this?

I have tried things like MSE and mutual information but a problem I encounter is that large binsizes often give me a small total error, but these are obviously less informative than histograms made with small binsizes, so I feel like I am missing something.

Thanks for any help,

M.

Comment: Not sure how meaningful this is, but you can look at for example Kullback–Leibler divergence between your distribution and the normalized histogram

Comment: Yea, I have tried various things like this. The more general problem I have is that the pdf has infinite precision - I can get its value for any x,y location. But the histograms have limited precision - I only know their value at the center of each bin. So what happens is that often when the histogram has super large bins the "error" can be very low even though the histogram is objectively bad.

Comment: define a probability density function whose value is the value of the normalized histogram everywhere inside each bin (a piecewise uniform distribution), then use the KLD to compare to your distribution